# Flutter: JAVA_HOME is set to invailed directorty

Tags: android, flutter

I installed flutter on Ubuntu 20.4 and checked flutter doctor(no issues)
I opened the test project and tried to run it and I get this error:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/java-15-oracle

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

here is the echo $JAVA_HOME

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

it is the right one, I've uninstalled oracle-jdk from my device but still getting this error

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your `JAVA_HOME` path to `jre` directory

in my case that is something like this

`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre`

Now go to your Environment variable and set your `JAVA_HOME` path to your `jre` directory

[image]